# Passing URL in URL with Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, electron, libvlc

I'm using Electron for a project of mine. I need to pass an URL between windows, which I'm doing by using the URL the following way:

```
function openWindow(url) {
    url=encodeURIComponent(url);
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
    var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
        win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/otherwindow.html?url=' + url);
}
```

On the receiving end (in `otherwindow.html`) I get the parameter this way:

```
var urlParam = function(name, w){
    w = w || window;
    var rx = new RegExp('[\?]'+name+'=([^\#]+)'),
        val = w.location.search.match(rx);
    return !val ? '':val[1];
}
```

I call this function as:

```
var decoded=decodeURIComponent(urlParam('url'));
```

And this all works fine. It's kind of ugly right now, but it works. Or so it seems. If I print out the decoded URL to the console it displays correctly. It seems to be fine, if I open up an Electron window with it, it displays the destination with no problem what so ever.

Here's the catch. I'm using [wcjs-player](https://github.com/jaruba/wcjs-player) for this project. In the destination page (`otherwindow.html`) is a wcjs-player instance, which would take the decoded URL and play the media located there with `.addPlaylist();` or `.vlc.play();`.

It works fine if I put the destination URL in a variable in the same page then l put it as a parameter to these 2 functions, even works if I use `encodeURIComponent();` and then `decodeURIComponent();` on said variable, so encoding the URL is not the problem. I even tried with a base64 encoding to pass between the pages, no success.

So judging from all this, I reckon that the problem is not the encoding itself, but the passing between pages. My (probably wrong) theory is that the URL might get somehow very slightly altered (losing/gaining some information, special characters maybe?), which wcjs-player is not prepared to handle, but Chromium is (since there's no problem with the Electron window using the result URL).

I have no idea to fix this, I've tried all my ideas. Did a fair bit of searching, but didn't really find anything useful. I can solve it another way, but that would involve opening and processing the same file twice - in both windows - which I'm trying to avoid.

I've pretty new to Javascript overall, so please excuse me if I'm missing something trivial. Any help is appreciated!